# database query retuyrns fields in one order, I want to display them in another

Tags: php, mysql

This probably has been answered (or should be basic knowledge), so please forgive the noob question...

I'm using the WP user_meta database to store advanced properties of a user.

Data is stored in this order (this is all for userid=15):

```
city = Altoona
state = PA
phone = 9999999999
name = Fred

I want to generate the output as
Fred, Altoona, PA, 9999999999
```

Here's the relevant PHP code:

```
 $my_exportlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_m_membership_relationships` WHERE `level_id` = '2' ");
foreach ($my_exportlist as $duser) {

$my_stationinfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` IN ('name', 'city', 'state', 'office') AND user_id ='$duser->user_id'");

foreach ($my_stationinfo as $myinfo) {
    $csv_output .= $myinfo->meta_value . ",";
    }
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

After the first answer I did this:

```
$my_stationinfo = $wpdb->get_results("GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) val_output
        FROM `wp_usermeta`
        WHERE `meta_key` IN ('name', 'city', 'state', 'office') AND user_id ='$duser->user_id'
        ORDER BY FIELD(meta_key, 'name', 'city', 'state', 'office'");
```

I get this error message...

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) val_output FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key' at line 1]
```

and after looking at a number of q/a and the linked mySQL instrucitons, I'm still baffled....

Further followup:
This is the current code

```
   $my_exportlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_m_membership_relationships` WHERE `level_id` = '2' ");
foreach ($my_exportlist as $duser) {

$my_stationinfo = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) val_output
        FROM   wp_usermeta 
        WHERE  meta_key IN ('primary_calls', 'city', 'state', 'office', 'contact_emerg', 'contact_routine', 'contact_backup', 'contact_billing', 'contact_eng', 'contact_web', 'contact_prod', 'contact_traffic') AND
               user_id = '$duser->user_id'
               ORDER BY FIELD(meta_key, 'primary_calls', 'city', 'primary_calls','state', 'office', 'contact_emerg', 'contact_routine', 'contact_backup', 'contact_billing', 'contact_eng', 'contact_web', 'contact_prod', 'contact_traffic')");
print_r($my_stationinfo);
var_dump($my_stationinfo);
echo $my_stationinfo->val_output[0] ;


foreach ($my_stationinfo as $myinfo) {

    $csv_output .= $myinfo;
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
```

The results:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [val_output] => Altoona,PA,814.943.8112,WRTA ) )


array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'val_output' => string 'Altoona,PA,814.943.8112,WRTA' (length=28)


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Users\Dev\Documents\Websites\contract.dev\wp-content\plugins\custom_plugin\index_page.php on line 40

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\Users\Dev\Documents\Websites\contract.dev\wp-content\plugins\custom_plugin\index_page.php on line 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) val_output
FROM   wp_usermeta 
WHERE  meta_key IN ('name', 'city', 'state', 'office') AND 
        user_id = '$duser->user_id'
ORDER BY FIELD(meta_key, 'name', 'city', 'state', 'office')
```

- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Still scratching my head on this one...I posted the new code and error message to the original message. I'm still confused after looking at the link you provided, along with several other searches related to GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: where is your `SELECT` keyword before `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Okay, got that fixed. Of course it would be forgetting a word!! Now I just have to figure out how to dump that val_output array into the csv output...thank you for your help!

Comment: Sigh...45 minutes and I'm no further...a hint what I should be doing?

Comment: `val_output` is separated by a comma by default. what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I want it to go into $csv_output, so it can be written to a file. I get "object of class stdclass could not be converted to string" when trying to do so.